# How do I change an image within a div every second unless hovered on link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I asked a question [How can I display an image in a div if  is hovered over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254383/how-can-i-display-an-image-in-a-div-if-a-is-hovered-over) and thanks to adeneo here is a solution ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ScAVW/)):

**Markup**:

```
<div id="imgs">
    <img src="http://www.flash-slideshow-maker.com/images/help_clip_image020.jpg" alt="image 1">
    <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/297522main_image_1244_946-710.jpg" alt="image 2">
    <img src="http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/uploads/monthly_05_2010/post-380028-12747928967239.jpg" alt="image 3">
</div>

<ul id="my-ul">
    <li><a href="#" class="img1">hover to see image1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="img2">hover to see image2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="img3">hover to see image3</a></li>
</ul>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('#my-ul a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('#imgs img').eq($(this).parent('li').index()).toggle(e.type==='mouseenter');
});
```

How to modify http://jsfiddle.net/ScAVW/1/ so that every second images change as 1->2->3->1->2->3->1... within div, unless link is hovered. If one of three links is hovered, the corresponded image displayed. It is stopped, when hovered. Once your mouse leaves, images start changing within div again.

Comment: What was the reason to downvote my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple image rotator. It will stop on `mouseenter` over a link, switching to the hovered image; and it'll resume on `mouseleave`, from the currently visible image.

```
var intervalId = setInterval(rotate, 1000); // rotate every 1s

function rotate() {
  var $imgs = $("#imgs img"),
      $visible = $imgs.filter(":visible").hide().index();
  $imgs.eq(($visible + 1) % $imgs.length).show();  
}

$('#my-ul a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
  var $imgs = $('#imgs img');
  if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
    clearInterval(intervalId); // stop, hammer time
    $imgs.filter(":visible").hide();
    $imgs.eq($(this).parent('li').index()).show();
  } else {
    intervalId = setInterval(rotate, 1000);
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ8E9/)**.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't stop the rotation when hovered.